# Issue bazel building pycoral due to C++ version

Tags: c++, c++17, bazel, google-coral

When I try to make pycoral, I'm getting the following error, which I believe is caused by one of the compilers using C++14, rather than 17.   Building on an Archlinux 6.3.1 system, using bazel 5.4.1.

```
In file included from bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_virtual_includes/flatbuffers/flatbuffers/base.h:217,
                 from external/flatbuffers/src/util.cpp:40:
/usr/include/absl/strings/string_view.h:52:26: error: 'string_view' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   52 | using string_view = std::string_view;
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/absl/strings/string_view.h:52:21: note: 'std::string_view' is only available from C++17 onwards
   52 | using string_view = std::string_view;
      |                     ^~~
/usr/include/absl/strings/string_view.h:686:8: error: 'string_view' does not name a type
  686 | inline string_view ClippedSubstr(string_view s, size_t pos,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/absl/strings/string_view.h:697:11: error: 'string_view' does not name a type
  697 | constexpr string_view NullSafeStringView(const char* p) {
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_virtual_includes/flatbuffers/flatbuffers/base.h:219:23: error: 'string_view' in namespace 'absl' does not name a type
  219 |         typedef absl::string_view string_view;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
Target //src:_pywrap_coral failed to build
```

I have already tried changing the version specified in the Makefile and the .bazelrc, but this did not seem to have any effect.

From Makefile:

```
COMMON_BAZEL_BUILD_FLAGS := --compilation_mode=$(COMPILATION_MODE) \
                            --copt=-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION \
                            --copt=-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 \
                            --cpu=$(CPU)
```

From .bazelrc:

```
build:linux --cxxopt=-std=c++17
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `build --cxx_language=c++17` in your bazelrc file.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I get an error.  As far as I can tell, the proper way to set that is what I had listed above.